# Fullpage.js with React - multiple calls

Tags: reactjs, fullpage.js

I need to implement a website in React which will have two pages and each of them will have horizontal slides. I checked different implementations of react fullpage but none of them seemed to be ok for what I need and therefore I've decided to use [https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js](http://Fullpage.js) with react. I want to call it multiple times - in two different components with different parameters. So in each of the components I put this code with different anchors:

```
componentWillMount() {
    console.log("Will ount technical");
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
      $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors:['welcome', 'data'],
        lockAnchors: false,
        slidesNavigation: true
      });
    });
  }
```

If I open each of the pages separately (after refreshing) both of them work but if I navigate to each of them I'm getting the following error: **fullPage: Fullpage.js can only be initialized once and you are doing it multiple times!**
I found on one of the forums that maybe I should use this: `$.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');`
But it's not working for me, if I use this code I'm getting an error **TypeError: $.fn.fullpage.destroy is not a function**

I'm not sure what should I do, can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE:

There's now an official React component for fullpage.js:

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage

---

The easiest way would be to use different fullpage.js containers.
This way you can conditionally initialise them:

```
if( $('#container1').length ){
     $('#container1').fullpage({YOUR_OPTIONS});
}

if( $('#container2').length ){
     $('#container2').fullpage({YOUR_OPTIONS});
}
```

Otherwise you can destroy any previously used instance, but you have to be careful to not call the destroy method before the first initialisation:

```
if(typeof $.fn.fullpage !== 'undefined'){
    $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
}
$('#fullpage').fullpage({YOUR_OPTIONS});
```